# Column Total at the end of SQL Pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have generated the following SQL Server 2008 pivot, and it gives me desire result.
I want to add total column at end of pivot, where I'm finding it difficult.

Please find the SQL I'm using for pivot

```
Select * from (
     Select Case when (podocstatus = 'CL') then 'Closed PO'
         when (podocstatus = 'OP') then 'Open PO'
         when (podocstatus = 'SC') then 'Short Closed PO'   
    end as POStatus, 
    YEAR(podate) as [Year], YEAR(podate) as [poyear] , LEFT (datename(Month,podate),3) as [pomonth]
    From PO_order_hdr
    Where podocstatus IN ('SC','CL','OP')
    ) as POnumber
PIVOT
(
    Count(poyear)
    FOR [pomonth]  IN (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)

)as PVT
```

Please help.

Comment: Your Desired result now show like postatus,year,jan,feb...,dec right? How you wanna get result?

Comment: `LEFT (datename(Month,podate),3)` will *never* generate a value of `Sept`.

Comment: Hello Magesh and Damein_the_unbeliever, @magesh as you are right it shows POstatus, year, Jan, Feb, Mar....Dec, i want total after DEC for each stautus rows which will listed below. damein_the_unbeliever - yes, i put SEPT instead of SEP, it was typo error, thanks for brought to attention.

Comment: Select *,(PVT.Jan + .... + PVT.Dec) as Total Can give you the result as you expected...

Comment: hello friends thanks for help.. i got the total at end.. i m looking for new 4 columns after TOTAL column.. that is quarter1, quarter2...q3..quarter4.. now how to sum - Jan+Feb+Mar/3.. Apr+May+June/3 ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to simply do something like this:

```
Select *,
    Jan + Feb + Mar + Apr + May + Jun + Jul + Aug + Sep + Oct + Nov + Dec AS [Total]
from
    ...
```

An alternative solution for the general case, would be to use a subselect. Move your inner query into a CTE, to make things a bit easier to work with:

```
WITH POnumber (POStatus, [Year], [poyear], [pomonth]) AS
(
    Select sase when (podocstatus = 'CL') then 'Closed PO'
         when (podocstatus = 'OP') then 'Open PO'
         when (podocstatus = 'SC') then 'Short Closed PO'   
    end as POStatus, 
    YEAR(podate) as [Year], YEAR(podate) as [poyear] , LEFT (datename(Month,podate),3) as [pomonth]
    From PO_order_hdr
    Where podocstatus IN ('SC','CL','OP')
)
select *,
    -- Subselect that counts the total for the given status and year:
    (select count([Year]) from POnumber T 
     where T.POStatus = PVT.POStatus and T.poyear = PVT.poyear) as [Total]
from POnumber
PIVOT
(
    Count(poyear)
    FOR [pomonth]  IN (Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec)
)as PVT
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, easiest solution had done the trick.. small details plays huge role... thank you very much for your kind advice and help. Actually i'm new to SQL, but self-learning through useful sites like stackoverflow and kind people like you.