# SQL query to get count of distinct values of columns in a same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with columns like Gender, Status.

The table value is something like this

| ID | Gender | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Male | A01 |
| 2 | Male |  |
| 3 | Female | A02 |
| 4 | Female |  |
| 5 | Unknown |  |
| 6 | Male |  |
| 7 | Female |  |
| 8 | Unknown |  |

I want to display

| Gender | Status | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Male | A01 | 1 |
| Female | A02 | 1 |
| Unknown |  | 0 |

I tried

```
SELECT 
    t3.Gender, t3.Status, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         t1.Gender, t1.Status 
     FROM 
         Consumer AS t1
     CROSS JOIN 
         Consumer AS t2 
     WHERE 
         t1.Status <> t2.Status 
         OR t1.Status <> t2.Status) AS t3 
GROUP BY
    t3.Gender, t3.Status
```

The final output something I want to display is [image]
Please help on this. Thanks

Comment: So the count is only for genders that have a value in status?

Comment: I don't understand using cross join here.

Comment: It's not completely clear what behaviour you want. You should expand your example to show the various possible data combinations that can occur and then show the results you desire. At present I could give a dozen queries that give those results, but have no idea if they're useful in general.

Comment: @MatBailie -- a dozen?  That seems like a lot -- maybe 3 or 4

Comment: Do you know how many status values there are before you run?

Comment: No status value can be any number. We need to take distinct value from both columns and display the count

Answer (score 2):

Since the desired results have now been updated, the solution is now much different.

Try:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(Status) = 1 THEN 'Total' ELSE Status END AS Status,
  --ISNULL(Status, 'Total') AS Status, -- This would not work is actual Status might be null
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Female' THEN 1 END) AS Female,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Male' THEN 1 END) AS Male,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Unknown' THEN 1 END) AS Unknown,
  COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM @Consumer
WHERE Status > ''
GROUP BY Status WITH Rollup
ORDER BY GROUPING(Status), Status
```

The above uses conditional aggregation to get the partial counts. `WITH ROLLUP` automatically creates a totals row. The `ISNULL()` sets a status label for that row (which would otherwise display as null). lastly, the `GROUPING()` in the `ORDER BY` places the rollup/total after the detail rows.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QXMf1-qG) or [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/igeZOEnJ) with expanded test data.

There are also ways to do this using a pivot table, but the above may be sufficient for your current needs.

Comment: Pivot table and with joins :)

Comment: Yup. Was just adding a comment to that effect.

Comment: Safer to use `case when grouping = 1` rather than `isnull`, just in case a null status ever creeps in.

Comment: @MatBailie - Excellent point. I've updated the above.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  *
       ,Male + Female + Unknown as count
from    t
pivot(count(id) for gender in(Male, Female, Unknown))p
where status is not null

union all


select  'Total'
       ,count(case when gender = 'Male' then status end)    as Male
       ,count(case when gender = 'Female' then status end)  as Female
       ,count(case when gender = 'Unknown' then status end) as Unknown
       ,count(status) as Total
from   t
```

| Status | Male | Female | Unknown | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A01 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| A02 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Total | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VtVwjyQb)

Comment: status values can be any number :(

Comment: Yes, very nice +1

Comment: The count column will always be 1 in the first select. I think you need something like `Male + Female + Unknown as count`. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651106/column-total-at-the-end-of-sql-pivot-query).) In the second select, there's a typo `'unkown'`. The query also assumes a case insensitive collation where `'Male' (data) = 'male' (sql)`.

Comment: @TN I fixed the typos and will look over the other points.

Comment: @TN I'm an idiot. You're obviously right. fixed. thank you!

Comment: Looks good. Here's a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X0BVf9D6) with expanded test data.

Answer (score 0):

You might be overthinking your requirements. Perhaps the following will work:

```
SELECT Gender, Status, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Consumer
GROUP BY Gender, Status
ORDER BY Gender, Status
```

It was not clear what you were expecting in your results for unknown gender. If you need special handling for unknown gender and/or blank status, you can add a `WHERE` condition to the above for the normal cases and the `UNION ALL` the results with a second query to handle the special cases.

```
SELECT Gender, Status, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Consumer
WHERE Gender <> 'Unknown' AND Status > ''
GROUP BY Gender, Status
  UNION ALL
SELECT 'Unknown' AS Gender, '' AS Status, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM Consumer
WHERE NOT (Gender <> 'Unknown' AND Status > '')
```

Comment: Check it out -- there is a totally new requirement on the output now.